# Finite field with nonprime cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, field-theory, finite-fields

In my textbook for discrete mathematics the following is stated:

> **Theorem**: $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field if and only if $p$ is prime.
>
> In the following we denote the field with $p$ elements by $GF(p)$ rather than $Z_p$. As explained later, "$GF$" stands for Galois field. Galois discovered finite fields around 1830.

However, there is a field with $p=4$ elements (right?) and clearly $4$ is not a prime. I  think that I am misunderstanding something fundamentally. Is it maybe that there are fields other than $\mathbb Z_p$ (what is the spoken name of this set?) that do not need to be of prime cardinality?

Comment: GF(p), with p prime, is the prime field of characteristic p. Every other finite field of characteristic p has the form GF(p^n) for some integer n>0.

Comment: Write $\Bbb F_p$ for $\Bbb Z/(p)$. A field of prime power order is not of the form $\Bbb Z/(p^n)$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$, but rather a quotient of $\Bbb F_p[X]$ by an ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial. The degree of this polynomial determines the cardinality of the quotient; $\Bbb F_p[X]/(f(X))$ with $\deg f = n$ gives the field $\Bbb F_{p^n}$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, there are finite fields other than $\Bbb Z_p$. The cardinal of such a field is always the power of a prime number. And, yes, there is a field with $4$ elements. It can be defined as $\Bbb Z_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Any finite field must be order of $p^{n}$ , where $p$ prime and $n$ is some non negative integer.

For order $p^{n}$ , just take Algebraic extension of the field $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is of degree $n$,
So, field with order $p^{n}$ can be represented as the quotient field $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]}{\langle\, p(x)\,\rangle} $, where $p(x)$ is some irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

Comment: You might add that $p$ has degree $n$. (and also that for any $n$, there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$).

Comment: @Bernard I didn't say,,,for every $n$...

Comment: @Bernard I show the way,,,if there is an irreducible polynomial over that field ,,,,then we can find such extension.. As,,the other answer said..

Comment: It's not directly related to the O. P., but it is a natural question, once you know a finite field has cardinality a prime power, to ask whether there exist finite field of  very prime power.